# Windows XP install using USB not booting

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, windows-xp, usb

I have Windows 7 installed on my laptop, instead of it I want to install Windows XP. I have created bootable USB using Rufus from Windows XP iso file (GetIntoPC website). My first boot device is set to my USB which is recognized by BIOS. However, the USB just skips and BIOS boots Windows 7. Interestingly, I installed Windows 7 using that same USB too.

What have I tried:

- changing SATA mode in BIOS from AHCI to IDE and reverse.
- pressing F12 and choosing USB no matter that it's first in boot order already.
- trying to start the installation by opening setup.exe on USB while Windows 7 is loaded.
- changing USB ports.

What's weird: Before I installed Windows 7 again, I formatted whole HDD and Windows XP installation just didn't want to load while Windows 7 one did.

I know that XP is old and not supported by MS anymore.

How do I boot to Windows XP install thumb drive?

Comment: So your question is basically, why you cannot boot from USB device?

Comment: *the USB just skips and BIOS boots Windows 7* It means your USB is not recognized as bootable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as I used Rufus for quite a while without problems, I believe the problem is in the iso file. I will get a new one and try.

Comment: Changed the file, still same. The USB is not broken and Rufus works with Windows 7 and Linux Mint (tested).

Comment: IS that usb drive recognized on any other PC as bootable?

Comment: U should be aware that tryin2 install WinXP from USB is either a complete anacronism,or somewhat of an anacronism.People weren't really doing that back then.People started installing from USB in windows 7 days.A good way to install XP(and here I don't mean by USB) is either from a CD,or by making a little partition on the HDD, puttin the setup files on there,  and installing from there. It may b possible to install WinXP from USB but im just saying you should know it's a ludicrously unusual non-standard thing2 do.One could boot off a boot disk or make the little partition bootable eg `sys c:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I vaguely recall there was a hack to install it from USB but very few people ever did it, there was a long guide how to do it and it was a very fiddly process that removed any convenience one would think they were going to get!

You should be aware that trying install WinXP from USB is either a complete anacronism,or somewhat of an anacronism.

People weren't really doing that back then.People started installing from USB in windows 7 days.A good way to install XP(and here I don't mean by USB) is either from a CD,or by making a little partition on the HDD, puttin the setup files on there, and installing from there.

It may be possible to install WinXP from USB but i'm just saying you should know it's a ludicrously unusual non-standard thing2 do.  One could boot off a boot disk then run the setup off the hard drive, or make the little partition bootable eg `sys c:` and boot off there.

Something like this https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/578/windows-xp-installing-from-harddrive/

And there is something about smartdrv that will make it much faster.

Again, none of this is installing WinXP from USB.  But I can see from the comments you have made, you are really just looking to install it.  If somebody can point you to how to install it from USB then great.

The involvement of USB I'd suggest is you can make a Win9X USB boot disk  (in the past people may have done that or used a floppy), and you could have the installation files copied on there, that's the i386 directory on any windows xp cd. Then copy it from the USB, to your hard drive. And run the WinXP setup off the hard drive.

**UPDATE**

Here is a link saying how to do it, in a process that is not fiddly, or not that more involved than the more standard process of installing from a hard drive. Though it is installing from the USB.  https://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/how-to-make-winxp-bootable-usb-drive.htm   The key seems to be to run `E:\i386\winnt32.exe /syspart:C: /tempdrive:C: /makelocalsource.`

There are many guides online, usually involving tools that didn't exist at the time. And claim to make it work without the kind of extreme file fiddling i've seen some a classic old guide do. It may be worth trying them

<s>Note that some people are saying there is another issue that XP doesn't recognise SATA. If that's so, then XP would either give you a BSOD(a google of which would make it clear what the issue was), or XP would prompt you for them(I don't recall which but possibly the latter),</s>

There is a situation regarding XP and SATA, thanks to keltari for his comment and some pictures on this page for reminding me https://hexus.net/tech/tech-explained/software/1420-installing-windows-xp-3rd-party-sataraid-driver/  ,  XP doesn't have SATA drivers  and does prompts you to press F6 to install SCSI or RAID drivers. SATA is not SCSI and you may or may not want RAID or want to use RAID, but you push F6 there, to install your SATA driver.

Then you could use a usb floppy drive or you could just copy the files into the correct directory within i386, so that the setup finds them automatically. Some people here have mentioned "slipstreaming" and nlite.. IIRC slipstreaming is rebuilding an ISO, you don't need to as you have the i386 directory on (easily!) writable media, so you can manually add the driver file(s) just by copying them in.

Comment: XP works with SATA just fine.  However, XP has almost no modern SATA chipset drivers.  If XP doesnt have the driver, setup simply shows no drives to install to.  You have to add the drivers during the install.  XP will not bluescreen due to a lack of SATA support.  The real issue would be the newer the SATA controller, the less likely XP drivers will exist.

Comment: @Keltari thanks, btw I wouldn't say it's not a 'blue screen'  see https://hexus.net/tech/tech-explained/software/1420-installing-windows-xp-3rd-party-sataraid-driver/  ('technically' ;-) ) , looks like a blue screen to me, but not a BSOD ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Win XP installation package doesn't have USB drivers. As soon as BIOS executes bootloader/whatever and the then switches to Windows boot, your boot device is lost, and that's it. This is a similar problem we have today with Win7 and USB 3.0 controllers. To get WinXP installed, a heavy patching of install image is required, there might be some help on Google for that. Or you need to use a native SATA or PATA based CD-ROM to install, and then install USB drivers in normal way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it makes sense. This seems too complicated for me (don't have CD-ROM), but I may try it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to install Windows XP on a legacy laptop and I wanted to use a USB drive. The solution I found was to use [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/). Here are the steps I followed:

1. Download [YUMI Legacy](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/#YUMI-Legacy), because Windows XP doesn't support modern UEFI systems.
2. Make sure your flash drive is inserted and open YUMI.
3. Agree to the license agreement.
4. Select the correct USB device.
5. Choose "Single Windows XP Installer".
6. Browse and select the ISO where you downloaded it.
7. Click on "Create" and wait for the process to finish.
8. Once the process is finished, click No when it asks to add another ISO, and then finish YUMI.
9. You may now eject the USB and insert it into the machine you wish to install Windows XP on.
10. Enter the boot menu and select your flash drive or "USB" on the list. You should see a "MultiBoot USB" screen.
11. Open "Windows Installers", then open "Begin Install of Windows XP from [ISO name].iso (Stage 1)". This will load the setup.
12. Partition your drive however you'd like when asked, and format as NTFS.
13. Once Setup reboots your computer, boot back into the USB through the directions given before. Once YUMI comes up, open "Windows Installers", and open "Continue Windows XP Install from [ISO name].iso (Stage 2)". This will boot Windows into the second phase of the setup.
14. Once the setup is done then it will restart one last time.
15. Boot back into your flash drive, select "Windows Installers", and select "Boot Windows XP - If fails, reboot with USB removed (Stage 3)". This step may not be required for you, and if so, you may just boot off your hard drive normally.

As an aside: I personally used [Windows XP Delta Edition](https://xpdelta.weebly.com/xp.html) because its setup is pre-configured to work on modern machines.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to install XP preferably 64-bit onto a Dell Inspiron 660 for a friend who cannot stand Windows 7 or above the only way I have found this far is an interesting program called vhd XP it installs the entire operating system into a 10-gig virtual hard drive on a USB so you literally and take your operating system with you on your car keys

Answer (score 0):

try hitting F12 repeatedly. With some BIOS's, this will bring up a menu to select the device to boot from. Hopefully the USB drive will be listed there

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It all seems easy to do but once I've 'reformated the disk (I guess that's what I've done)… Where on earth am I supposed to type this command: E:\i386\winnt32.exe /syspart:C: /tempdrive:C: /makelocalsource ? And am I supposed to replace "winnt32.exe by winnt64.exe" if I used a 64bit ISO and finally am I supposed to write syspart: Disk 0: or: syspart: 0:?
Thanks for your help.